# Как запустить виртуальное окружение python через bash в vs code?

Tags: python-3.x

Начал изучать python. Использую VS code с bash в качестве терминала на windows. Не получается запустить `venv` через терминал. Перешел в папку с `venv` и ввел команду:

```
.\\Scripts\\activate
```

И ничего не произошло. По крайней мере терминал никак визуально не изминился. На стандартное из документации

```
.\Scripts\activate
```

bash убирает слеши и ругается, что такой команды нет. Что я делаю не так?

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если у вас там Linux окружение (WSL), то скорее всего никакого Scripts не будет, будет `venv/bin/activate`, и активировать нужно через `source venv/bin/activate`. Ну или командой ls посмотрите какие там реально папки есть.

Comment: @insolor У меня Windows. Папка Scripts есть и activate есть, но в качестве консоли я использую bush

Comment: Вообще, bash или bush?

Comment: @insolor ошибся - bash

Comment: Если все папки действительно есть, пробуйте использовать прямые слеши (`/`) вместо обратных.

Comment: @insolor Так команда проходит, но в виртуальное окружение я не попадаю. В консоли этого не видно. Сейчас добавлю скриншот.

Comment: @insolor добавил.

Comment: Тогда пробуйте сделать как написано в первых строках файла activate на скриншоте и активировать через `source ./venv/Scripts/activate`

Comment: @insolor Вроде бы помогло. Спасибо, не догадался открыть activate сразу. Неудобно вышло...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй использовать fish раньше у меня была винда и меня с окружением вечно возникали проблемы я смог решит эту проблему поставив терминал убунту на винду

```
source venv\Scripts\activate.bash
```

если не сработает

```
python -m venv new_proj_env
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
new_proj_env\Scripts\activate
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]